# How to retrieve profile-picture and workphone from user profile

Tags: development, user-profile-property, picture

How can I get profile image from spuser and also phone?

```
Guid fieldID1 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("User").Id;

string valueField1 = item[fieldID1].ToString();
SPFieldUserValue userField = (SPFieldUserValue)item.Fields[fieldID1].GetFieldValue(valueField1);
SPUser user = userField.User;

text1.Text = user.Name;
text2.Text = user.Email;
```

Right now my code gets name and email from the user

Answer (score 2):

You could consider at least two options:

1. retrieve an additional user properties from `User Information List`
2. retrieve user properties via `User Profile`

**Option 1**

```
var userInfoList = site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList;
var userInfoItem = userInfoList.GetItemById(user.ID);
var pictureUrl = userInfoItem["Picture"];
var workPhone = userInfoItem["WorkPhone"];
```

**Option 2**

```
var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
var userProfileManager = new UserProfileTypedManager(serviceContext);
var userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(user.LoginName);
var workPhone = userProfile["WorkPhone"].Value;
var picture = userProfile["PictureURL"].Value;
```

Comment: Most explained. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the User Information List, to grab the Picture column contents. It's a hidden field, so you might have to write a console app to get the columns, or find a reference somewhere online.

Tobias Zimmergren did a blog post on getting user data from the User Information List from an SPUser object:

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx

---

And You can also try to do something like this:

```
public string GetUserPicture(SPSite site)
{
    string userAccount = "domain\\account";

    ServerContext ctx = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
    UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(ctx);
    UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(userAccount);

    return  up["PictureUrl"].Value;
}
```

Also check these Links if they are helpful for you

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339/getting-user-photo-from-spuser-using-wss-object-model)
[2.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/get-user-profile-display-picture-information-in-sharepoint-2128/)
[3.](https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/get-the-users-profile-image-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

You can read Photo Url using User Profile Service API.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteurl"))
{
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
    UserProfile currentProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(user.LoginName);
    ProfileValueCollectionBase profileValueCollection = currentProfile.GetProfileValueCollection("PictureURL");
   //profileValueCollection.Value.ToString()
}
```